# Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

why do I get a not defined error when defining this function with single quotes?

example:

```
rotator.doStuff =  function(num) {
        //do stuff
        rotator.timer = setTimeout('rotator.doStuff('+num+')',500);
}
```

Comment: what's not defined?  what's the exact error here?

Comment: Why not just `setTimeout(function() { rotator.doStuff(num) },500);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is the contents of an IIF.

When using a string, `rotator` will be resolved in the global scope, and it won't be available there, thus the error.

You should try this. Now `rotator` will resolved in lexical scope, from which it is accessible.

```
rotator.timer = setTimeout(rotator.doStuff.bind(rotator, num), 500);
```